# Wie findet man heraus, ob eine Konstruktion ein Anglizismus ist?

Tags: etymology, anglicism, pseudo-anglicism

Regelmäßig wird bei zeitgenössischen sprachlichen Veränderungen des Deutschen vermutet, dass es sich um einen Anglizismus handelt. Mitunter liegt dieser Zuschreibung eine Haltung zugrunde, die der Veränderung ablehenend gegenübersteht – in diesen Fällen wird die Veränderung als fremd markiert, indem sie als Anglizismus aufgefasst wird.

Beispiele aus dem Forum hier sind die Streitfälle:

- *etw. macht Sinn*
- *unoffiziell*

Ob es sich bei einem Wort oder eine Konstruktion tatsächlich um einen Anglizismus handelt, ist oft empirisch schwer zu klären.

Welche empirischen Methoden gibt es, die Hinweise darauf geben können, ob ein Wort ein Anglizismus ist oder nicht?

Wie lässt sich der Einfluss einer parallelen englischen Konstruktion auf das Deutsche quantifizieren?

Answer (score 6):

Proof für vokabularische Anglizismen (und *Pseudo*anglizismen, wie das "Handy") zu finden, ist ziemlich easy - Verwendet jemand "Killer" und meint nicht das Dorf auf der Schwäbischen Alb, ist das klar ein Anglizismus. Semantische, formale, und syntaktische Anglizismen sind wesentlich mehr tricky, nachzuweisen.<sup>(*)</sup>

Dein Beispiel "unoffiziell" ist eins, bei dem sich ein Anglizismus ziemlich sicher *nicht* nachweisen läßt. Den meisten germanischen Sprachen ist gemeinsam, dass sie die Negation von Adjektiven mit "un-" (oder "on-" wie im Niederländischen, "o-" wie im Schwedischen) bilden. Ist ein Adjektiv assimilliert genug (und damit seine Fremdworteigenschaft hinreichend verwischt), kann es ohne weiteres auch als Fremdwort so verneint werden wie ein "ursprünglich deutsches" (was auch immer das sein mag) Adjektiv. Die Tatsache, dass  ein deutsches Wort einem Wortbildungsmechanismus folgt, den es zufällig im Englischen aufgrund der gemeinsamen Sprachherkunft auch gibt, macht noch lange keinen Anglizismus daraus.

Viele vermeintliche Anglizismen lassen sich nach diesem Schema verneinen (Das ist allerdings kein empirischer Ansatz, den du zu suchen scheinst).

Ein empirischer Ansatz wäre möglicherweise, die Entstehungs- und Verbreitungsgeschichte von vermuteten Anglizismen zu untersuchen - Sollten sie zuerst in einem anglophilen Umfeld (z.B. in britischen/amerikanischen Garnisonsstädten) oder in einem Umfeld, dass durch seine Nähe zur englischen Sprache vermeintlich eine soziale Aufwertung erfährt ("Manager-Speak") aufgetreten und erst danach in den allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch eingesickert sein, wäre ein empirischer Beweis zumindestens naheliegend (das scheint meiner Meinung nach z.B. bei "macht Sinn" oder "in 2022" der Fall zu sein).

*Erstes Auftreten* eines bestimmten Phänomens läßt sich natürlich extrem schwer nachweisen. Die Wahrnehmung von sprachlichen Phänomenen findet eben hauptsächlich durch Menschen statt und ist deswegen ausgesprochen subjektiv.  Moderne soziale Medien machen den Nachweis aufgrund ihrer Durchsuchbarkeit möglicherweise einfacher, sind auf der anderen Seite mit einem hohen anglophilen Bias behaftet und geben nicht unbedingt die gesamte Sprachentwicklung wieder.

<sup>*</sup> Bonuspunkte für das Finden aller Anglizismen in diesem Absatz

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Dies ist eine Community-Antwort. Alle können etwas dazu beitragen. Das Ziel ist es, die Liste an Indizien in einer Antwort zu bündeln.</sup>

## Präliminarien

Die Frage, ob ein sprachliches Phänomen (ein "Linguem") des Deutschen ein Anglizismus ist, ist keine **binäre** Frage: Es kann etwa sein, dass ein englisches Linguem einen gewissen Einfluss auf die deutsche Sprache gehabt hat; es kann aber gleichzeitig sein, dass auch andere Faktoren einen Einfluss hatten, vielleicht sogar ausschlaggebend waren. In dieser Hinsicht ist die Eigenschaft, ein Anglizismus zu sein, eher eine **graduelle** Eigenschaft.

Es ist daher sinnvoll, nach **Indizien** zu fragen, die einen Hinweis darauf geben, ob das Linguem unter dem Einfluss des Englischen ins Deutsche gekommen ist.

## Indizien dafür, dass ein englisches Linguem einen Einfluss hatte

- Das deutsche Linguem taucht in Übersetzungen aus dem Englischen zuerst auf
- Das deutsche Linguem taucht in Übersetzungen aus dem Englischen gehäuft auf

## Indizien dafür, dass das deutsche Linguem *nicht* auf Einflüsse aus dem Englischen zurückgeht:

- Das Linguem ist im Deutschen (oder in einer Vorstufe des Deutschen) früher nachweisbar als im Englischen
- Jedes Indiz dafür, dass das Linguem aus einer anderen Sprache ins Deutsche gekommen ist

Answer (score -1):

Naja ein riesen Problem an der Sache ist ja das sowohl das Englische als auch das Deutsche sich ganz gerne bei Latein und Französisch bedienen/bedient haben und dementsprechend sehr viele "Fremdworte" bereits Teil der Sprache sind die gar nicht mehr jedem als Fremdworte ins Auge fallen würden. Also zum Beispiel "offiziell", das anscheinend auf Lateinische Wort für "zum Amt gehörend" zurück geht.

Und die Verneinung mit un- ist im deutschen auch gebräuchlich also theoretisch wäre unoffiziell möglich. Allerdings gibt es bereits das Wort "inoffiziell" das ist so verbreitet und gebräuchlich ist das unoffiziell sich einfach nur falsch anhört und so als hätte man das Wort "unofficial" in seine Einzelteile zerlegt ähnliche Worte im Deutschen gesucht und dann wieder zusammengesetzt  anstatt das Wort als ganzes zu übersetzen.

Die Nachbarländer übersetzen das meistens auch eher mit "nicht offiziell" oder "inoffiziell" mit Ausnahme von vielleicht den Niederlanden, wobei die ja als Mittlersprache zwischen Deutsch und Englisch gehandelt werden. Also die Annahme das es sich hier um schlecht übersetztes Englisch handelt liegt schon nahe. Aber wenns sich etablieren würde und größere Verwendung finden würde, wäre es vermutlich schwer das als offensichtliches Fremdwort nachzuweisen.

Bei Sinn machen hat man im Grunde das gegenteilige Problem. Eigentlich macht "Sinn machen" keinen Sinn. Denn machen impliziert das man etwas herstellt aber "Sinn" kann man nicht machen. Allerdings ist es so gebräuchlich das sich abgesehen von Sprachwissenschaftlern und Puristen da im Grunde keiner mehr dran stört, also im Gegensatz zu "unoffiziell" würde es vermutlich die Mehrheit nicht vom Sprachgefühl was "falsch" oder "befremdlich" einordern.

So ähnlich sieht es mit "realisieren" aus, was streng genommen "real machen" bedeutet, also man geht von einer Idee zu einem real existierenden Konstrukt über. Was dann mit der Englischen Bedeutung von "sich etwas bewusst werden" kollidiert, wenn man zum Beispiel den Tod einer Person realisiert. Also das eines ist "sich darüber klar werden", das andere ist entweder die Personifikation des Todes beschwören oder jemanden umbringen. Allerdings gibt es das Wort ja bereits von daher ist es in dem Sinne kein Fremdwort und den semantischen Übergang zur Ausweitung der Bedeutung wird man später schwer nachweisen können.

Zumal man sich ja noch philosophisch irgendwo retten kann das "sich etwas bewusst werden" ja auch heißen kann das "man es zum Teil seiner Erfahrung der Realität machen" und damit ja auch eine gewisse Realität erzeugt oder verändert wird. Also diese Verwendung ist auch nicht ganz abwägig.

Comment: Ich war eigentlich weniger an einer Erörterung der beiden Beispielfälle interessiert, als vielmehr an allgemeinen Methoden. Die Antwort geht in meinen Augen an der Frage vorbei.

Answer (score -2):

Bei Sprachen mit Empirie zu kommen ist schonmal schwierig, aber generell "gilt":

- Wenn es englisch ausgesprochen wird: Handy, surfen, beamen...
- Oder es ein Wort ist, welches genau so auch im Englischen verwendet wird: Smarthphone, Baby...

Comment: Was meinst du mit "Bei Sprachen mit Empirie zu kommen ist schonmal schwierig"? 

In meinen Augen sind die von dir genannten notwendige, aber bei Weitem keine hinreichenden Kriterien dafür, ob ein Wort ein englisches Lehnwort ist. Es handelt sich darüberhinaus auch gerade nicht um empirische Kriterien. "Anglizismus" ist auch ein weiterer Begriff, der nicht nur Wortentlehnungen bezeichnet. Ich habe meiner Frage zwei Beispiele dafür hinzugefügt.

Comment: Empirie definiert der Duden als "Methode, die sich auf wissenschaftliche Erfahrung stützt, um Erkenntnisse zu gewinnen". Da sich Anglizismen vorallem aber aus Umgangssprache entwickeln (und diese ja meist nicht auf explizite, nachvollziehbare Regeln stützt), gehe ich davon aus, dass man Anglizismen nicht wirklich empirisch klassifizieren kann. Es existieren mit Sicherheit also maximal die zwei grundlegenden Verfahren aus der Antwort, Andere sind auch möglich, aber subjektiv und damit nicht empirisch.

Comment: @xtay: Umgekehrt wird ein Schuh draus. Die ganze Sprachwissenschaft basiert auf nichts anderem als auf Empiriie. Erst war die Sprache da, dann hat man deduktiv aus der Sprache ihre impliiziten Regeln hergeleitet. Geschrieben und gesprochen wurde lange, bevor sich jmd. Gedanken über Regelwerke gemacht hat. Und das gilt natürlich unterschiedslos für Umgangssprache. Dass sich v.a. dort Anglizismen entwickeln halte ich für eine falsche These - im Gegenteil: In Fachsprachen, wenn Experten primär englische Quellen studieren, die für ein internationales Publikum verfasst  wurden und auch selbst publ…

Comment: …publizieren, hat man oft einen englischen Begriff schneller parat, als einen deutschen. Abschließend die Fragen: Wie stellt man fest, wie ein Wort ausgesprochen wird? Und wie, ob es genauso im Englischen verwendet wird?